# LaTeX to HTML conversion with Kile

Tags: conversion, html, ps, png

I am using Kile to convert a `.tex` file to HTML (LaTeX to web) but when I look at the HTML page it does not show me the images. I tried including them in PostScript and PNG but still the HTML page does not show the images.

Here is an example that show the LaTeX file with the image:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
text
.
.
.
\begin{figure}[hr]
     \centering
      \resizebox{0.6\textwidth}{!}{\includegraphics[angle=-90]{./sey1.png}}
       \label{sey1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I tried with both PostScript and PNG and got the same result. It also complained about using the `graphicx` package.

Any suggestions?

Comment: We will need to see the exact detail of this issue, for example 'complained' does not give us enough information to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should use `\includegraphics` only with `.eps` image format.

Then, you should try to compile your tex like this: 
`.tex`->`.dvi`->`.html` or `.tex`->`.dvi`->`.ps`->`.html`.